# What's the correct way to protect against multiple sessions getting the same data?

Tags: mysql, transactions, locking

Let's say I have a table called `tickets` which has 4 rows, each representing a ticket to a show (in this scenario these are the last 4 tickets available to this show).

3 users are attempting a purchase simultaneously and each want to buy 2 tickets and all press their "purchase" button at the same time.

Is it enough to handle the assignment of each set of 2 via a `TRANSACTION` or do I need to explicitly call `LOCK TABLE` on each assignment to protect against the possibility that 2 of the tickets will be assigned to two users.

The desire is for one of them to get nothing and be told that the system was mistaken in thinking there were available tickets.

I'm confused by the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/lock-tables-and-transactions.html) which says that the LOCK will be implicitly released when I start a TRANSACTION, and was hoping to get some clarity on the correct way to handle this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a transaction, MySQL takes care of locking automatically. That's the whole point of transactions -- they totally prevent any kind of interference due to overlapping requests.

Comment: So, to be clear, for the duration of my TRANSACTION on the tickets table all other sessions' attempts to interact with that table will be held at bay until I call commit or rollback?

Comment: InnoDB does locking at the record level, not the entire table. But the general point is that other transactions will never see partial results of a transaction. Until you commit, none of your changes will be visible to other sessions, so they'll always see a consistent version of the database.

Comment: @GeniaS: Yes, **but** they can be executed immediately after that and may overwrite the changes in an inconsistent manner (for example re-selling the same ticket again) based on information that your application has retrieved *before* that first concurrent transaction was committed. Depends on how you structure your tables.

Answer (score 1):

You could use "optimistic locking": When updating the ticket as sold, make sure you include the condition that the ticket is still available. Then check if the update failed (you get a count of rows updated, can be 1 or 0).

For example, instead of

```
UPDATE tickets SET sold_to = ? WHERE id = ?
```

do

```
UPDATE tickets SET sold_to = ? WHERE id = ? AND sold_to IS NULL
```

This way, the database will assure that you don't get conflicting updates. No need for explict locking (the normal transaction isolation will be sufficient).

**If you have two tickets, you still need to wrap the two calls into a single transaction (and roll back if either of them failed.**

Comment: Interesting approach, thanks... I was hoping to make better sense of the difference between Transaction and Lock, but I appreciate a totally alternative method and will keep it in mind.

Comment: @GeniaS: Not really a different approach. It builds on top of Transactions and Locks (which are handled under the hoods by the database).